# Interval of convergence of $\sum\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, contest-math, power-series

#### Question:

What is the Interval of convergence of $\sum\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}?$

(a)(-1,1]

(b)[-1,1)

(c)Neither

#### My work:

Radius of convergence,
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=1$$
How do I know if the interval is open or closed?

*Source:GATE 2010.*

*The answer was given as (b)*

Comment: is that a $x^n$?

Comment: Substitute $x=1$ resp. $x=-1$ in the series and check for convergence.

Comment: Here is another question concerning this series: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2002778

Comment: @MartinSleziak: That's a suitable duplicate target, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it seems to be. (If there are other questions about this, I certainly would not be surprised - this was the first one I found.)